# bibtex compiling error

Tags: texmaker

I wrote a very simple script like following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Then I got error message like this:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6730) The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

I am on Mac OS, using texmaker, miktex. I did some search and the closest I think is 
[Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations)

However, it seems a windows based solution, and I prefer not to change much of my current setting because I do need to use bibtex.

What should I do to create an simple latex document on Mac OS? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the .aux file and try again.

Comment: @Fran I have tried, but it did not work. Same error.

Comment: Your description suggests that texmaker isn't set up correctly -- specifically, that when you click on the "quick build" button, BibTeX rather than LaTeX is executed by default. If that's the case, the solution consists of opening the drop-down window associated with "quick build" and selecting "LaTeX" as the default.

Comment: How can you run `bibTeX` without a `\bibliographystyle{}` and a `\bibliography{}` command? (And same about `biblatex` ... where is the package included) ? ... Edit: Oh... I see ... See Mico's comment!

Comment: @Mico Yes when I choose LaTex instead of quick build, it went through! Thanks. Can you put your comments as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @NickXTsui - Done. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(elaborating on my earlier comment...)

The description contained in your posting suggests that texmaker wasn't set up correctly -- specifically, that when you click on the "quick build" arrow-shaped symbol, BibTeX rather than LaTeX is executed by default.

If that's the case, the solution consists of opening the drop-down window next to the "quick build" arrow-shaped symbol and selecting "LaTeX" as the default.